# MySQL PHP group by day and total for each day

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a table in a mysql database with 3 columns: id, value and tstamp. My tstamp column is in TIMESTAMP format, ie: 2011-01-21 08:32:22

What i hope to achieve is use PHP to display a break down of a total for each day. I cant think of a way to query the table, in pseudo code: select * from table group by day(part of tstamp) and add all numbers together from the value column for each day"

Is this going to be possible?

Thanks alot

EDIT:

I have this query in combo with the accepted answer's code:

```
$sql = "select date(tstamp), sum(".$column.") from mash group by date(tstamp)";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                      $strXML .= "<set name='".date("G:i:s", strtotime($row["date"])).  "' value='".$row["sum"]."' color='AFD8F8' />";
                }
```

How do i access the array values in $row correctly?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want MySQL to return you the value you are looking for in ONE QUERY you can use:

```
select date(tstamp), sum(value)
  from your_table
 group by date(tstamp);
```

Comment: @benhowdle89 I think $row[0] will contain the date, and $row[1] will contained the summed value.

Comment: Take a look at mysql_fetch_assoc (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) if you want to use names instead of array indexes as you are exposing in your code sample. Also, a print_r($row) will help you debug/inspect what's inside the array you are getting.

Comment: One more quick question, this works great for "day", what would i have to do to get "month" or "year"?

Comment: @benhowdle89 for year, you can use `year(tstam)`. For month, you can use `month(tstamp)` or `concat(year(current_timestamp), "-", month(current_timestamp))`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using this

```
DATE_FORMAT(datestamp , '%Y') as year //for grouping over year
DATE_FORMAT(datestamp , '%Y-%m') as month //for grouping over month
DATE_FORMAT(datestamp , '%Y-%m-%d') as day //for grouping over day
```