# Get Daily Active Users for the last 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, join, logging, group-by

I have a log on our app that logs all user activity along with a unix timestamp and I now want to create a function that will return the data needed to display the number of DAU each day in the last 2 weeks. Ive googled around a bit , but I have been unable to find a straightforward question on Stack regarding how to even start to go about such a query . Maybe my querying knowledge just is not advanced enough , excuse my ignorance if this is the case. I just have no idea how to group individual dates + unique user totals in a single query.

my table is setup as following

---

### |LOG_ID | TYPE_OF_REQUEST | USER_ID | TSTAMP |

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT last few days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713056/mysql-select-last-few-days) (then read about [`GROUP BY`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4759718/1446005)).

Answer (score 0):

You can start by filtering

```
WHERE TSTAMP <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
```

To filter only the two last weeks

And then

```
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

Perhaps combining a `COUNT(TYPE_OF_REQUEST)`

Depends on what info you are trying to achieve